# Google Chrome extension to detect following a link outside of the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension that is supposed to add the tab to chrome when it is opened (in addition to the tabs that open in accordance with the "On startup setting").  The problem that I am experiencing is that my Intranet page opens in a new tab even when users click on a link in an email or a document of any kind.  This can be really confusing to the users.  Desired behavior is that if user clicks on a link that opens Chrome, only that link will open up and not the intranet tab.  I was thinking that if I could detect that Chrome has opened because link was followed (as opposed to opening chrome directly) I would just bypass the call for the Intranet tab.  problem is that I am not finding a way to do this.  Any thoughts?  Below is the code for the plugin and it runs with background and tabs permissions.

```
var newURL = "http://intranet/";


chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(loadIntranet);
function loadIntranet(){
chrome.tabs.query({url: "http://intranet/*"}, function(results) {
    if (results.length == 0) {
    
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
};

        });
    }
```